# Prove that $(\mathbf{1}\times\textbf{u})\cdot\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{u}\cdot(\mathbf{1}\times\textbf{v})=\textbf{u}\times\textbf{v} $

Tags: tensor-products, index-notation

As the title, $\textbf{u}$ and $\textbf{v}$ be two vectors. The problem didn't explain, but I think $\textbf{1}$ is a dyadic?
I did try using index notation, and here is the following steps I did.

---

Proof:

$$(\mathbf{1}\times\textbf{u})\cdot\mathbf{v}
=(\mathbf{e}_{i}\mathbf{e}_{i}\times{u}_{j}\mathbf{e}_{j})\cdot{v}_{k}\mathbf{e}_{k}={u}_{j}{v}_{k}[\mathbf{e}_{i}(\mathbf{e}_{i}\times\mathbf{e}_{j})\cdot\mathbf{e}_{k}]$$

$$={u}_{j}{v}_{k}[\mathbf{e}_{i}(\mathbf{e}_{k}\times\mathbf{e}_{i})\cdot\mathbf{e}_{j}]
=-{u}_{j}{v}_{k}[\mathbf{e}_{i}(\mathbf{e}_{i}\times\mathbf{e}_{k})\cdot\mathbf{e}_{j}]
=-(\mathbf{e}_{i}\mathbf{e}_{i}\times{v}_{k}\mathbf{e}_{k})\cdot{u}_{j}\mathbf{e}_{j}
$$

$$=-(\mathbf{1}\times\textbf{v})\cdot\mathbf{u}=-\mathbf{u}\cdot(\mathbf{1}\times\textbf{v})$$

---

Finally, I got $(\mathbf{1}\times\textbf{u})\cdot\mathbf{v}
=-\mathbf{u}\cdot(\mathbf{1}\times\textbf{v})$ which is different from answer $\mathbf{u}\cdot(\mathbf{1}\times\textbf{v})$
Were there anything I'm missing or logical misunderstanding that make outcome wrong?
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: What did you compute for $1\times u$? Can you find a definition of the vector $1$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde In the course handout, identity dyadic define as $ \mathbf{1}=\mathbf{e}_{1}\mathbf{e}_{1}+\mathbf{e}_{2}\mathbf{e}_{2}+\mathbf{e}_{3}\mathbf{e}_{3}$

Comment: The simplest interpretation is $1$ is the vector whose components are all $1$, i.e. $\mathbf{e}_1+\mathbf{e}_2+\mathbf{e}_3$.

Comment: What am I missing? How can a dot product, which is a scalar, be equal to a cross product, which is a vector?

Comment: @J.G. I have added a few remarks to my answer which addresses these questions. I cannot help thinking that in $3d$ this dyad calculus is rather gratuitous.

Comment: @martycohen . See comment and update to answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the course handout defines the dyadic $\mathbf{1}$ as $\mathbf{e}_i\mathbf{e}_i$ (with summation over $i=1,2,3$) it is extremely likely, see [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics#Product_of_dyadic_and_vector), that it also defines

- $\mathbf{1}\times\mathbf{u}$ as $\mathbf{e}_i(\mathbf{e}_i\times\mathbf{u})$ where the cross product between vectors $\mathbf{e}_i$ and $\mathbf{u}$ is the ordinary one.

Since
$$\mathbf{e}_1\times\mathbf{u}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\-u_3\\u_2\end{pmatrix},\quad\mathbf{e}_2\times\mathbf{u}=\begin{pmatrix}u_3\\0\\-u_1\end{pmatrix}\,,\quad\mathbf{e}_3\times\mathbf{u}=\begin{pmatrix}-u_2\\u_1\\0\end{pmatrix}
$$
and since $\mathbf{e}_i(\mathbf{e}_i\times\mathbf{u})$ is most likely a dyadic (tensor product) we get (with summation over $i=1,2,3$)
$$\tag{1}
\mathbf{e}_i(\mathbf{e}_i\times\mathbf{u})=\begin{pmatrix}0&-u_3&u_2\\u_3&0&-u_1\\-u_2&u_1&0\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
It is obvious and well-known that the multiplication of this anti-symmetric matrix with a vector $\mathbf{v}$ equals the ordinary cross product $\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v}$.

Remarks:

- By [1]  all products $\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}$ are tensor (outer products) and thus nothing else than matrices:
  $$
  \mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{a}\otimes\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}^\top=
  \begin{pmatrix}a_1b_1&a_1b_2&a_1b_3\\a_2b_1&a_2b_2&a_2b_3\\
  a_3b_1&a_3b_2&a_3b_3\end{pmatrix}\,.
  $$
- For the unit basis vectors $\mathbf{e}_i$ we therefore have
  $$
  \mathbf{1}=\mathbf{e}_1\mathbf{e}_1+\mathbf{e}_2\mathbf{e}_2+\mathbf{e}_3\mathbf{e}_3=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\,.
  $$
- The cross product of a dyad and a vector, $(\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b})\times\mathbf{c}$,
  is defined as the dyad $\mathbf{a}(\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c})$
  where $\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c}$ is an  ordinary cross product.
- Applying this to the individual summands of the dyad $\mathbf{1}$ I get from
  linearity
  $$
  \mathbf{1}\times\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{e}_1(\mathbf{e}_1\times\mathbf{u})+\mathbf{e}_2(\mathbf{e}_2\times\mathbf{u})+\mathbf{e}_3(\mathbf{e}_3\times\mathbf{u})
  $$
  which leads to (1) above.

Comment: @yclin Was this answer helpful ?